# Message Indicator doesn't indicate new messages

Tags: 12.04, indicator, email

I recently set up Gwibber and Thunderbird, but whenever there is new mail or tweets, the message indicator icon doesn't change to the new message icon. I'm currently using Faenza-Ambience icon theme, but I have also tried the default ubuntu-mono-dark theme and the problem still persists. Is this a bug or feature? How can I get it to indicate new messages?

I'm on 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Unity or GNOME shell?

I don't know about Unity, but Thunderbird doesn't really integrate that well with the messaging tray in gnome-shell. One possible workaround, that might also work in your case, is to install a Thunderbird extension like FireTrayR or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your message icon won't show up when you get a new email unless you open Thunderbird. This is because Thunderbird doesn't run in the background and check for new mail.

Not sure about Gwibber but I think you can change what things are notified in the program settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually have all the apps open except for empathy.